# Sencha all-classes.js has missing views

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to optimize an existing project comprising a bunch of elements.

I am trying to combine a bunch of small javascript files into one file using the sencha build in mechanism.

I have successfully executed the following commands:

```
sencha create jsb -a ./app.html -p ./app.jsb3

sencha build -p app.jsb3 -d .
```

The last command creates app-all.js and all-classes.js files.

My gui is loading faster now.

By examining the app.js and all-classes.js file I see that non of my view objects were saved in all-classes.js file (only "store" object code was saved in all-classes.js file ).

It will be great if somebody can help me with a workaround.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Do you have all of your `requires` directives correct?  Every file that you use should be included somewhere in your app using this, starting with including your main view in `app.js`.

Comment: Yes, I have all views objects listed in app.js file in requires: [] and vews: [] sections.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to find a working workaround.

I use the following command to copy all views code to a single js file and include it into the project:

```
grep -l "Ext.window" app/view/*.js | xargs cat > code/all-views.js
```

And in index.html I added the following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="code/all-views.js"></script>
```

Now my whole project is loaded from a small number of JS files.

Best regards,
Alex

Comment: Nice. You should accept your answer for others to find it more easily.

Comment: Erf, I forgot that "you can also accept your own answer, but you must wait 48 hours to do so". Sorry.